# Angular material - autocomplete component dropdown section does not stick to the input field

Tags: angular, angular-material

The autocomplete component from angular-material is not working as expected inside the MatDialog component. The drpodown section from autocomplete component does not stick to the input field.

stackblitz link - [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s698hp)

to reproduce - Goto above stackblitz. Click on "open popup" button. Click on the "Pick One" autocomplete field. The options will open as dropdown. Then scroll the bodu of popup. Notice the dropdown section of autocomplete component does not stick to the input field. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the drop down is actually part of the `cdk-overlay-container` and not part of the `matAutocomplete`... only triggered by the `matAutocomplete` to be rendered in the `cdk-overlay-container`, with a calculated `top` position based on the placement of the `matAutocomplete input` field at the time of the user interacting with the field.

> **Important Note:** The CDK container is transparant and the full height and width of the root browser view port, overlaying everything
>   in your app.

If you were to put that `matAutocomplete` in the middle of the dialog, open, then close... scroll position a bit, open `matAutocomplete` again... you will notice it renders in the new position with the newly calculated `top` and not the old....

Once it is rendered and on the DOM via the `cdk-overlay-container` however, there is no real-time scrolling event to force the `cdk-overlay-container` to "re-calculate" the top position with the scroll event.

> I think the idea is that users who are interacting with an
>   autocomplete typically are not scrolling around while doing so... as
>   they are actively searching for a value... once selected... they then
>   proceed with UI navigation.

If you notice, once you are interacting with the `mat-select` in that same dialog, you are not able to scroll while it is open... I think they did that for this specific reason as it too uses the `cdk-overlay-container` to render the dropdown... I am not exactly clear on why the `matAutocomplete` doesn't behave the same.

---

If you put this in your component css, then open your dialog, you can see the dialog and the drop down are part of this "hidden" container.... even the autocomplete before opening the dialog exposes this container and you can see the drop down is not red... but everything below it is.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container{
  background-color: #ff000087;
}
```

Additional information on CDK here.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Comment: I did notice how `mat-select` worked inside of the dialog. The scrolling was disabled and with this approach there is no need to recalculate the position. This seems to be a better approach than recalculating the position on scroll. But not sure how to achieve that behaviour with autocomplete.

I also noticed how autocomplete worked when on the same level as body. It did recalculate the position and scroll along with the rest of the page.

Comment: I found some bugs already raised for this. [github bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7897#issuecomment-409326058) this solution worked for me. But there still some issues like the dropdown sections now scrolls with the input field, but it goes out of the dialog instead of being hidden. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s698hp-szjm5p)

Comment: It makes sense why it is working on the main body, as the logic to recalculate is there by default. Not surprised about it scrolling beyond the boundaries of the dialog as it is still an overlay design and not truly inside of the `MatDialog`... I see you have been active in this issue over the last 4 days https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10079 so it would seem you knew all of this already. Keep tracking that issue and hopefully someone will post how to apply the blocking strategy for the auto-complete. I too attempted it in your stackblitz but not able to figure it out.

Comment: for anyone ending on this thread, https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10079#issuecomment-447967821. Though not a fix, this is the best workaround and the UI does not feel broken.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s698hp-lubekt

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya is there any option for angular JS?

Answer (score 2):

Add `cdkScrollable` to the scrolling div.

- Import `ScrollingModule` in app.module.ts
- Add `cdkScrollable` to the scrolling div

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; overflow-y: auto;" cdkScrollable>
 <p>Angular Material, the ultimate design</p>
 <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
     {{option}}
   </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
 <p>Angular Material, the ultimate design</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ScrollDispatchModule is now deprecated. What do we use instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-drawer, .mat-sidenav {
  &[cdk-scrollable], &[cdkScrollable] {
    .mat-drawer-inner-container {
      overflow: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

Just try it on your globe SCSS file.