# Mat-autocomplete doesn't stick / laggy

Tags: angular

Here I have an example, if you're trying to open the autocomplete and scroll the autocomplete doesn't stick to input, it's changing the top. What can I do to solve this issue?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? It doesn't happen anything like that when I tried it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material - autocomplete component dropdown section does not stick to the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778831/angular-material-autocomplete-component-dropdown-section-does-not-stick-to-the)

Comment: You're right, my bad.. On the form add 'style="height: 600px;"' and try to scroll and you'll see that that dropdown doesn't stick

Comment: @Daniel Piñeiro no, are not duplicated.

Comment: @petietertje what actually you want? can you improve your question.

Comment: @arunkumar to prevent autocomplete from sticking when i'm scrolling the window

Comment: @petietertje I think your stackblitz working as expected